# Web tool that can obfuscate a URL with a password

Tags: web-apps, url

I'm looking for a tool that can obfuscate/scramble a URL with a password.

Only the holder of the password can deobfuscate the URL.

Thank you.

Comment: Andy K, please note that on Stack Exchange sites, questions/answers shouldn’t contain "fluff" like greetings, signatures, thanks etc. (which is why I had removed it with [my edit](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/posts/49455/revisions) to retag your question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not asking a desktop application, I can recommend [thinfi](https://thinfi.com/) I'm using it for a while and very happy with it.